# Is it correct to write 40+ in a sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

If the amount of something, let's say locations, has a minimum of 40 but fluctuates to up randomly, can 40+ be used? Would "around 40," "about 40" or something similar be more appropriate for a formal paper.

Ex. Their company has 40+ locations.

Comment: Well, "40+" explicitly means "no less than 40", or "40 or more", and "around 40" or "about 40" would permit, e.g., 38, which is excluded by the stricter "40+". As to when to use digits vs writing out numbers in prose: typographic rules in English vary more than grammatical or orthographic rules, so while one style guide or another may mandate a particular method, there is no formal "correct" or "incorrect". When in doubt, skew more formal, or adopt the conventions of your favorite style guide (consistently!), e.g. the Chicago Manual of Style.

Answer (score 5):

As Dan Bron points out in a comment above, "40+" isn't interchangeable with "approximately 40," "about 40," "roughly 40," or "40 or so." Rather, it amounts to saying "at least 40," "no less than 40" or "a minimum of 40." For this reason, expressions of the form "40+" often appear in the context of ages, where qualifying individuals in the category "40+" are in no danger of falling below the threshold number of 40 at some future time owing to natural fluctuations or the vicissitudes of fortune. Once people reach 40+ years old, they stay 40+ years old.

In contrast, a company that operates in 40+ locations has no guarantee that the total will never fall below 40 in the future. For that reason, "40+" is less stable and reliable when applied to company locations (for example). The term "40+" can still work in such contexts, of course, but the risk of future error is somewhat problematic. In part that's because, in a base-10 system, most people encountering the term "40+" will interpret it as meaning "40 or more but less (or fewer) than 50"; after all, if the number were 50 or greater, we would expect the approximation to be set at 50+.

There is also an aesthetic issue to consider in connection with the form "40+": If you're talking about a less-than-huge countable number of locations that ought to be identifiable with a moderate amount of effort, readers may wonder why you don't give the exact number. Especially in a formal context, using "40+" seems imprecise at best and lazy at worst when applied not to a numerical interval or category (such as "businesses with 40 or more locations") but to a particular business that has a particular number of locations (43, say, or 47). The more formal the setting and subject area are, the less welcoming readers are likely to be toward approximations of two-digit numbers. That may explain why a consulting firm that I occasionally do copyediting work for reports in its boilerplate "about us" paragraph that it is "a private company with 82 offices in 46 countries," rather than "a private company with 80+ offices in 40+ countries." Precision sounds better.

Comment: I'd love to upvote this (as I love to upvote all your detailed and conscientious answers), but apparently I've been profligate today and spent all my votes. The best I can offer this is virtual +1.  Thanks again!

Comment: I think you answered your own question in the first part. 40+ accounts for a slow growth (or very slow decay) of the company and would not become factually false/require an update when a new location opens in the next few months/a year. X+ is also of course sometimes used to create an illusion of inflated numbers. I also think when reporting mission-uncritical numbers over 10, dropping the last significant digit makes information much easy to read and, most importantly, remember. Less noise = more retention.

Answer (score 2):

To give it a slightly higher degree of formality, you can write 40+ as ***40-plus*** locations.

This convention is frequently employed in news stories and books:

> Previously, these processes were decentralized and handled differently across **30-plus** locations.<sup>1</sup>
>
> Centier maintains its status as an independent bank despite expanding to **40-plus** locations in five counties and more than $1.6 billion in assets.<sup>2</sup>
>
> More than 100 local musicians perform in **50-plus** locations throughout the city, including grocery stores and nightclubs, parks, restaurants and plazas.<sup>3</sup>
>
> Now, with **60-plus** locations in five states, la Madeleine chain is thriving and handheld computers are a key part of its next wave of innovation.<sup>4</sup>

---

<sub>S O U R C E S</sub>

<sup>1</sup>*Excellence in Practice Vol 5: Innovation and Excellence in Workflow and Business Process Management*, Future Strategies, Incorporated, 2003.

<sup>2</sup>*BizVoice*, Volume 10, Indiana Chamber of Commerce, 2007.

<sup>3</sup>*April in Tallahassee blooms with springtime arts and entertainment*, Atlanta Journal-Constitution, March 2, 2016

<sup>4</sup>*Handheld Computers for Chefs*, Susan Sykes Hendee and Mohammad Al-Ubaydli, 2007

Comment: This is actually the first time I've ever seen "40-plus"...and I have to say, it looks odd to me!

Comment: @KristinaLopez - Well, plenty of other examples abound, [on the web](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%2240-plus%22), [in the news](https://www.google.com/search?q=%2240-plus%22&safe=off&tbm=nws), and [in books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q="after+40-plus").

Comment: Ha!  Well, now you know I'll see it EVERYWHERE! :-D